# DNS issues when using VPN in Linux Mint

Tags: virtualbox, vpn, dns, virtualization, linux-mint

I'm using Windows8 as my host OS, and are running a Linux Mint VM on virtualbox, with its network being virtualized as NAT. I'm using Ciscos AnyConnect VPN to get access to a certain network. The Cisco anyConnect is run from my host OS(Windows). When I run AnyConnect at the host-os, the VM is able to connect to the vpn-network as well.

However, when I run AnyConnect at windows, the DNS lookup of the Linux Mint VM stops working. (It's internet connection otherwise is fine). The DNS of windows still works though.

/etc/resolv.conf looks identical both when the DNS fails(vpn connected on windows-host),
and when DNS works correctly(vpn is disconnected on windows-host).

Any clue why and how to fix it?

Comment: The AnyConnect client might be redirecting your DNS lookups in Win8 to your corporate network's DNS servers, while the VM won't have such a redirect.  Do you know your company/organization's DNS server IPs?  You could try adding that to the /etc/resolv.conf.

Comment: so your resolv.conf points to your LAN DNS server, which is inaccessible when the host connects to the VPN. Do you want the traffic from the VPN to hit your LAN or VPN'ed network? if the former, enable split tunneling in your hosts VPN client so that lan traffic is not sent onto the VPN, and your existing DNS configuration shoudl continue to work. if the latter, you will have to reconfigure the guests dns to point to one accessible on the VPN network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had encountered a similar issue, and i ended up finding that all the DNS queries on my machine were getting handled by DNSmasq. VPN connection was skipping updating the `/etc/resolve.conf` file because of that.

You can confirm if `dnsmasq` is running on your machine by running following command

```
netstat -anp | grep -i dnsmasq
```

If yes, then update your `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, and add following entries.

```
server=/.mydomain.com/10.1.1.11

server=/.my-domain.com/10.1.1.11
```

I have discussed this in my [blog](http://chawlasumit.wordpress.com/2014/06/15/linux-mint-openconnect-vpn-dns-issues/) here